# hibernate 5 order of execution in inserting onetoone entities

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-5.x

I have very complex structure with multiple tables to simplify I will post small example

I have 4 entities

```
A -> entityId
B -> entityId (A- -Onetoone B)
C -> entityId (A- -Onetoone C)
D -> entityId (A- -Onetoone D)
```

In DB I have constraint of FK for entity D onto entity C (ideally incorrect but changing structure is not possible due to high impact)

After moving to hibernate5 insertion order is affected and it raises **ConstraintViolationException**
for table D as it tries to insert D before C

Is there any way I can manually reorder table inserts such as C should be executed before D ?

Comment: Change the structure... Or rather create the proper mapping so that hibernate knows the other. Trying to do that yourself leads you down a slippery path.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: we are using oracle DB

Comment: @M.Deinum I know that's the best solution, but since its complex structure and existing one we want to explore other options, isn't there some way to manage EntityInsertAction map ?